# How to convert Indian tamil to unicode string

Tags: .net, unicode, tamil

I have a requirement to send a Tamil SMS lets say "தமிழ்" using a service provider.
The service provider wants only Unicode string.
I don't want byte array, .

Comment: What language are you programming? Java? .NET?

Comment: Do you expect to see these Unicode characters? (2980,2990,3007,2996,3021) or (\u0ba4,\u0bae,\u0bbf,\u0bb4,\u0bcd)

Comment: like this (2980,2990,3007,2996,3021)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, all strings in your application are already encoded in the Unicode character set.

If you want to see the individual characters and character codes that make up a given string you can use this Console Application example to print them to the screen for analysis. I can't see how you are interfacing with your SMS service provider, so this example will need to be modified to suit your needs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string str = "தமிழ்"; // this is already a unicode string.

        byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        char[] stringChars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(stringBytes);

        foreach (var chr in stringChars)
        {
            // unicode character code
            var unicoded = ((int)chr).ToString();

            // hex character code
            var hexcoded = @"\u" + ((int)chr).ToString("X4").ToLower();

            // print to VS output window
            Trace.WriteLine(chr + "     " + unicoded + "     " + hexcoded);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Liked it